# How can I make my visitors "Like" my Facebook Page in Asp.Net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I want to add a face book "like" box on my website but confused how  can i do this that when ever a visitor come to my site he can like my page on facebook.
May i do this using javascript or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple cut & paste exercise:

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 3):

Get your Like button code from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and paste it in your website.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook offer [a tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to generate the code you need.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a standard 'like button' like [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/)?